# Is there a wagon rig tutorial?

Tags: rigging

For a couple of millenia now, people have been using towed objects,

[image]

either towing the objects themselves, using animals, or more recently, machines.

Given the number of carts, wagons, trailers, farm equipment, and the like, I would expect that someone would have created a tutorial on how to rig such a model, but after several hours of searching, I've not found one and would like to find either a tutorial, or a rig to study.

Comment: These things are done by simulating rigid bodies. You need to find or study a rig implementing rigid body physics.

Comment: Roubal's rigs for 2.49 http://3d-synthesis.com/tutorialsenglish.html in particular http://3d-synthesis.com/tutorials/Trucks-AutodriveSystem-V2.blend  Needed to rotate the road.y 90degrees, and the rotate wheel script needs upgrading.